# Finding a credible region with a normal posterior

Tags: bayesian, posterior, credible-interval

I have a posterior distribution that is normal and I want to find a credible region for which $\mu$ lies. However, I am having trouble integrating the following posterior:

$\int \pi(\mu|x) = \int_{0.5872}^{0.7424}\frac{1}{\sqrt{8\pi/101}}exp(-\frac{(\mu-56/101)^2}{4/101})d\mu$

Will my answer contain something to do with the error function?

Regards

Comment: Rewrite the integral as $\dfrac{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}{\sqrt{8\pi/101}}\int\dfrac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}exp\bigg(-\dfrac{(\mu-56/101)^2}{4/101}\bigg)d\mu$. Now you can do error function work on the integral and then multiply by the constant when you’re done.

Comment: @Dave Thanks for your answer. I tried this but then realised that I forgot to add that I have pre-existing values on the integral. I have updated my question.

Comment: Then evaluate the error function at those values.

Comment: Hi Dave, I've been trying this for a little while with not great success. I have not worked with the error function before, do you think you could give me a hint?>

Comment: Evaluate the CDF at those points using some software like R.